# php 101 DateTime using atom format

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the DateTime class to output the current time in DateTime::ATOM format.

I'm not sure if I'm even using it correctly. Or do I have to import a library or maybe turn on a wamp php module.

I'm getting "syntax error, unexpected T_NEW" error

here is the code:

```
<?php
function d()
{

     $df =  new DateTime(DateTime::ATOM);
    echo $df;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'd use `DateTime` like this:

```
$time = new DateTime;
echo $time->format(DateTime::ATOM);
```

The constructor (`new DateTime`) expects the *time* you want to create the object for, the *format* doesn't matter at this point. You specify the format when *outputting* the time.

Having said that, the error you're getting seems pretty unrelated and may not have anything to do with that specific line.

Comment: Thank you,
well, I'm getting this error now :
Fatal error: Class 'DateTime' not found.
I'm using Wamp 5 with:
Apache version :  Apache/1.3.31 (Win32)
PHP version :  5.0.2
MySQL version :  4.0.21-nt-log

Comment: @airnet You should seriously upgrade your PHP (and MySQL) version, 5.0.2 is very much obsolete and does not support `DateTime` by default. You can use `date(DATE_ATOM)` instead.

Comment: new DateTime(); need parenthese

Comment: Thanks Doak, I added the (). But the error still remains. Thanks Deceze, I will upgrade. :)

Comment: An object when creating require to have parentheses to use default constructor...

Comment: @Daok Try it, it works without! Parentheses are only *required* when supplying arguments to the constructor. The constructor is always called regardless.

Comment: More better: `echo (new DateTime())->format(DateTimeInterface::ATOM);`

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
 $x = date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime('2009-11-04T19:55:41Z'));
```

or

```
 $x = date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
```