# How to get date/time with timezone in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get a date in this format using php but i cannot find the correct format.

`2014-02-20T12:47:39.444-0700`

my current code:

```
 $MTtime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
 $UTCtime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
 $MTtime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $UTCtime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: What means .444-0700 ?

Comment: @edcaracas i think .444 is ms and -0700 is the time zone offset, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is probably ATOM time you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554799/php-101-datetime-using-atom-format

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for the function? [It's right there on the page.](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @DaOgre for pointing me to the ATOM time format.

here is how I finally got it to work:

```
$UTCtime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$data['logDateTime'] = $UTCtime->format(DateTime::ATOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using gmDate:

```
gmDate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u-Z");
```

http://www.php.net/gmdate